# Can i use IdHTTP in the OnExecute Event (Indy)?

Tags: delphi, indy

Can i use IdHTTP in the OnExecute Event (Indy) ? like this :

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  H: TIdHTTP;
  Data, Res: string;
begin
  Data := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
  H := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    Res := H.Get(Data);
  finally
    H.Free;
  end;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(Res);
end;
```

Thank you

Comment: I would suspect so.  So is the "Data" a url that you are then doing a "Get" on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just try it.